# How do I tell the C++ compiler on a supercomputer that my R package requires C++0x?

Tags: c++, r, c++11, rcpp

I have written and built an R package that depends on `Rcpp` and requires the `C++0x` standard (for using the `tgamma` function in C++). I have tested the package on various desktop computers and operating systems, and it always seems to install and work fine. However, I would also like to use the package on an HPC server. When I try to install the package there in my local R library tree using `R CMD INSTALL test` (where `test` is the name of the package), I get the following error message from the compiler:

> /usr/include/c++/4.4.7/c++0x_warning.h(31): catastrophic error: #error directive: This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming ISO C++ standard, C++0x. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x compiler options.
>     #error This file requires compiler and library support for the upcoming \
>      ^
>
> compilation aborted for Metropolis_Sampler_Beta_Edgewise_Cpp_Statistics.cpp (code 4)
>   make: *** [Metropolis_Sampler_Beta_Edgewise_Cpp_Statistics.o] Error 4
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘test’

It basically tells me that I should enable C++0x support when the compiler is called (as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22877664/how-do-i-enable-std-c0x-from-command-line) post). Yet, I thought adding the statement `CXX_STD = CXX11` to the `src/Makevars` file in the R package would actually tell the compiler that this version needs to be used. And indeed that seems to be the case on various desktop computers I have tried. So my question is: how can I tell the compiler on the server that this C++ version should be used for compilation? Alternatively, how else can I install the package?

On the server, I load the module for R by entering `module load math/R` on the terminal before trying to install the package, and it reports back that the following modules were loaded:

> Loading module dependency 'compiler/intel/13.1'.
>
> Loading module dependency 'numlib/mkl/11.0.5'.

**Edit 1**: The server is a German university cluster called bwUniCluster. It is based on KITE 2.0/RHEL6.5/Lustre 2.5.2. As far as I can tell from the module message reported above, it seems to be the Intel C++ Compiler XE (ICPC) version 13.1.3. But actually I have no clue about compilers, so if you need to know anything more specific, please let me know.

**Edit 2** It's also possible to execute `module load compiler/gnu/4.9` on the terminal before I try to install the package. This results in the following error message (similar as the one above), which leads me to think that this is not a version problem:

> /pfs/data1/software_uc1/bwhpc/common/compiler/gnu/4.9.2/bin/../include/c++/4.9.2/bits/c++0x_warning.h(32): catastrophic error: #error directive: This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
>     #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
>      ^
>
> compilation aborted for Metropolis_Sampler_Beta_Edgewise_Cpp_Statistics.cpp (code 4)
>   make: *** [Metropolis_Sampler_Beta_Edgewise_Cpp_Statistics.o] Error 4
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘test’

**Edit 3**: One of the comments suggests that both the R package and R itself need to be compiled using the same compiler version. Is this correct? R was built using g++ 4.4.7 on this machine. Does this mean that the only feasible solution is to convince the sys admin to recompile R with the other 4.9.2 compiler and provide it as a new module? I find this hard to believe, given the following sentence in the "[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Using-C_002b_002b11-code)" manual:

> On these platforms, it is necessary to select a different compiler for C++11, via personal or site Makevars files.

Comment: Ask the sysadmin of the cluster (perhaps to install GCC 4.9) Alternatively, try to compile your thing on your Linux laptop (perhaps linking it statically.

Comment: With g++ 4.4.* you will have a hard time.  That compiler is pretty old.

Comment: I sent three e-mails to the local support technician, but he never replied. Will try to track him down in his office. It's also possible to run ``module load compiler/gnu/4.9`` on the terminal, which results in g++ 4.9.2, but I get the same error message. @Dirl Edelbuettel: Does your comment also apply to g++ 4.9.2?

Comment: g++ 4.9.* will work just fine; read "Writing R Extensions" as I told you in your other question.  Your problem on that cluster may be that you probably want R _and_ your code compiled with the same compiler for successful dynamic linking.  Viel Glueck.

Comment: You don't need to have the admin recompile R - as a matter of fact they are unlikely to oblige your request unless you campaign for it. You can do it yourself though if you have access to build tools on the server. Just get the source tar ball and follow instructions. Also, I could be horribly mistaken, but from the error message all it seems to want is some flags explicitly enabling functionality

Comment: R comes with six manuals. One is called [R Installation and Administration](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html).  I suggest you read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was indeed to recompile R on the server with a newer compiler, in this case Intel 14 (as discussed in Edit 3 in the original post). The sys admin was so kind to set up a new module for this R version.